# How are $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_n|z^n$ related?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Given a power series $f(z)=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty} c_nz^n$, then there is an associated power series $[f](z):=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty} |c_n|z^n$. We know that $f$ and $[f]$ have the same circle of convergence. Generally, can we say more about them?

For example, whether $[f]$ has more convergent points or more singular points on the circle of convergence?

A similar question is that if $[f_1]=[f_2]$, then are there some general connections between them?

Comment: I would not use the notation $|f|$ here: people would think it was $\left| \sum_{n} c_n z^n \right|$.

Comment: @Robert Israel right, the notation $[f]$ would be better. This can be viewed as an equivalence relation among power series?

Comment: without additional hypothesis, there isn't much to say beyond the obvious that if $[f]$ converges on the full circle (which is equivalent of course with convergence at $z=R$), then $f$ does; one can easily construct examples where $[f]$ converges at all but $R$ (the radius of convergence) and $f$ diverges both at $R$ and at other points, and viceversa, one can contruct examples where $f$ converges everywhere, but $[f]$ diverges at some points (including of course $z=R$ per force)